# Implement exclusive access to an EFS/NFS directory

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, nfs, distributed-system, amazon-efs

The goal is to have a shared EFS store used by multiple containers where each container knows what directory it needs and only one container at a time can write inside this directory. If multiple containers started with the same target directory only one should acquire the lock, others may fail or keep waiting.

The only requirement is that data in one directory is *never* modified by two containers.

Considerations:

1. NFS file locking is not applicable as the situation when an nfs client loses connectivity releasing the lock therefore allowing another process to write to the directory while still writing itself when nfs client restores the connection is possible.
2. Using consensus based key-value store to decide whether a directory is available for access. Requires reliable fencing in case a container declared dead comes back. Is it possible for disk writes?
3. Using fencing agent installed together with containers which kills containers if it detects connectivity issues. Are there reliable options here? How to deal with detection/kill lag?

Is there a reasonable way to solve this? Are there good alternatives (which don't involve redesigning the app)?